# How to test file upload to webservice in Cucumber-Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, cucumber

Hi
Given I have a webservice which accepts file uploads.
And I want to test it in Cucumber
When I put the following code in Step Definition
    `post '/webservice', 'picture[file]' => File.new(Rails.root.join(@path_to_file), 'rb')`
Then I should see the saved file

Unfortunately, this is not the case.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I should be using fixture_file_upload.
[How do I test a file upload in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178587/how-do-i-test-a-file-upload-in-rails)