# attachment_fu testing in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, ruby-on-rails-3, attachment-fu

I am trying to write specs for a working file upload functionality using attachment_fu. However, the sample code given by the author for testing requires me to require `action_controller/test_process` so that I have access to `ActionController::UploadedStringIO` class. I have used this before in rails 2.x but for rails 3, it fails to locate the `test_process` file.

How do I go ahead with testing the file upload functionality in rails 3?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I was able to use fixture_file_upload just fine with Rails3 and rspec.

I just added `include ActionDispatch::TestProcess` to the spec_helper.rb, and then passed something like the following as the filedata:

```
fixture_file_upload(Rails.root.join("spec/support/test.png"), 'image/png')
```

EDIT: Something I upgraded changed the behavior of this to always include the fixtures path, so I switched to this instead of fixture_file_upload:

```
Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(Rails.root.join("spec/support/test.png"), 'image/png')
```

Comment: +1 for the last comment on using `Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new`! with `include ActionDispatch::TestProcess` I was somehow getting strange behaviour with factory girl...

Answer (score 4):

I'm working on testing file uploads in rails 3 right now, although I don't know how helpful my answer will be.  Would it be possible for you to change the test?  Personally, I'm using a Cucumber/Capybara approach.  Capybara's DSL defines

```
attach_file('Image', '/path/to/image.jpg')
```

Personally this seems a better way to test than interacting with the StringIO object...feel free to retort.

Answer (score 3):

This was somewhat tricky to find for Rails 3

You can still use the `fixture_file_upload` function, but you have to add:

`include ActionDispatch::TestProcess`

To your test case.

This didn't work at all with Rspec. I just had to grab the file itself and post the file directly.