# fixture_file_upload has {file} does not exist error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Below is my testing code for uploading file.

```
describe "file process" do
 before(:each) do
   # debugger
   @file = fixture_file_upload('test.csv', 'text/csv')
 end

 it "should be able to upload file" do
  post :upload_csv, :upload => @file
  response.should be_success
 end
end
```

However, when I run **rspec spec**, it produced me the error below

```
Failure/Error: @file = fixture_file_upload('test.csv', 'text/csv')
 RuntimeError:
   test.csv file does not exist
 # ./spec/controllers/quotation_controller_spec.rb:29:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I have googled alot of places but I still couldn't find out what's the reason behind it. Any idea?

Comment: Found one solution from SO [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966263/attachment-fu-testing-in-rails-3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966263/attachment-fu-testing-in-rails-3). Apparently, I have to replace fixture_file_upload with this line `@file = Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(Rails.root.join('spec/fixtures/test.csv'), 'text/csv')`

Comment: fixture_file_upload not working with Rails 3.1?

Comment: I started seeing this after we upgraded to 3.2

Comment: it seems it's broken in rails 3.2, check this issue on github: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/252

Answer (score 31):

Fixture_file_upload basically still works. You just need to make sure the fixtures path in your `spec_helper.rb` file is uncommented & correctly set to the `spec/fixtures` path & to include `ActionDispath::TestProcess`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include ActionDispatch::TestProcess

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  ...
```

And where you are specifying the file in your tests, be sure to precede your file name with '/' like the following example:

```
describe "POST /subscriber_imports" do
  let(:file) { { :file => fixture_file_upload('/files/data.csv', 'text/csv') } }
  subject { post :create, :subscriber_import => file }
  ...
end
```

The absolute path to the file is the base path specified in `config.fixture_path` plus the relative path specified in `fixture_file_upload` function call. So, in this example, `file.csv` must be placed in `#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/files/data.csv`

Comment: Also note the `include ActionDispatch::TestProcess`. This in particular fixed the issue for me

Comment: `include ActionDispatch::TestProcess` is what fixed it for me as well. The odd part is that we had used `fixture_file_upload` fine in other rspec tests, but it failed for a new one. May have been that this new spec was scoped in a module.

Answer (score 6):

This is how I did it with `Rails 6`, `RSpec` and `Rack::Test::UploadedFile`

```
describe 'POST /create' do
  it 'responds with success' do
    post :create, params: {
      company: {
        logo: Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new("#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/test-pic.png"),
        name: 'test'
      }
    }

    expect(response).to be_successful
  end
end
```

[DO NOT include `ActionDispatch::TestProcess`](https://github.com/honeybadger-io/honeybadger-ruby/blob/a18b1c3c4d912f96f1a3cb1435cc8a50e436f7f5/lib/honeybadger/notice.rb#L487-L496) or any other code unless you're sure about what you're including.

Comment: fixture_file_upload is Shortcut for Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(File.join(ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest.file_fixture_path, path), type)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the most voted answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260394/test-a-file-upload-using-rspec-rails) question, you have to put the file under {Rails.root}/spec/fixtures/files