# Rails testing fileupload receives error "File not found"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I am using RSpec (Rails 3.2) to test my controllers. I have a controller which also contains a fileupload (using CarrierWave), but I keep getting the error:

> Failure/Error: "image" => fixture_file_upload(Rails.root.join('spec',
>   'fixtures', 'files', 'image.png'), 'image/png')
>        RuntimeError:
>          .../spec/fixtures/files/image.png file does not exist

In my controller I have defined the image upload like this:

```
  def valid_attributes
{ "title" => "My own title",
  "description" => "Something cool",
  "image" => fixture_file_upload(Rails.root.join('spec', 'fixtures', 'files', 'image.png'), 'image/png')
}
```

end

I have of course checked that file exists, but might there be something else that I have overlooked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems you have to use `Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new` rather than `fixture_file_upload` in Rails 3.2:

```
def valid_attributes
  { "title" => "My own title",
    "description" => "Something cool",
    "image" => Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(Rails.root.join('spec', 'fixtures', 'files', 'image.png'), 'image/png')
  }
end
```

See this SO question/answers: [fixture_file_upload has {file} does not exist error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011425/fixture-file-upload-has-file-does-not-exist-error)