# FactoryGirl and PaperCip attachement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, paperclip, factory-bot

I've got a model :

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :model do
    mini_image { fixture_file_upload(Rails.root.join('spec', 'photos', 'rails.png'), 'image/png') }
    name "Test model"
  end
end
```

When a run rake spec, I received this error:

```
NoMethodError:
   undefined method `fixture_file_upload'
```

I already add to my spec_helper this

```
config.include ActionDispatch::TestProcess
```

The only way I find to made my Factory working is to add this line at the beginning of my models.rb file, but it's not very clean :

```
include ActionDispatch::TestProcess
```

Anyone have another solution ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on here with your error, but using `Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(...)` as an alternate approach is discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966263/attachment-fu-testing-in-rails-3

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to add this in your `spec_helper.rb`, outside of `RSpec.configure` block.

```
FactoryGirl::SyntaxRunner.class_eval do
  include ActionDispatch::TestProcess
end
```

Comment: Or to test_helper.rb if you're not using RSpec.

Comment: I first thought this was the solution for my set-up as well (Rails 4.2.5, RSpec 3.1.0, FactoryGirl 4.4.0). However, somehow after quitting Guard (which was sitting in the background) and running rspec on the command line, it crashed on these lines in my `spec_helper.rb` file. A very straightforward solution was to simply put `include ActionDispatch::TestProcess` in the factory file where I'd used `fixture_file_upload` (luckily just one factory).