# RSpec converting POST params to string? (testing file uploader)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I am using this block of code to mimic the way files are uploaded:

```
def mock_file
  file = File.new((Rails.root + "public/checklist_items_template.csv"),"r")
  image = ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new(
          :filename => "checklist_items_template.csv", 
          :type => "text/csv", 
          :head => "Content-Disposition: form-data;
                    name=\"checklist_items_template.csv\"; 
                    filename=\"checklist_items_template.csv\" 
                    Content-Type: text/csv\r\n",
          :tempfile => file)
  return image
end
```

In the rspec test it is POST'd to the controller:

```
post :create, :legal_register_id => "1", :register => {"file" => mock_file}
```

But it breaks this line in the actual controller:

```
CSV.parse(params[:register][:file].read.force_encoding('UTF-8'))
```

Because params[:register][:file] is being interpretted as a string instead of an actiondispatch object:

```
undefined method `read' for "#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000108de3da8>":String
```

Is this standard behavior for rspec? Is there a way to pass objects via params?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not RSpec that's converting your param objects to strings, it's Rails 3.1.

You can get around it by using `fixture_file_upload` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8296330/156109).

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use this: ActionController::TestUploadedFile
instead of an actual ActionDispatch file

See this other S/O question for an example of use:
[How do I test a file upload in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178587/how-do-i-test-a-file-upload-in-rails)

Though this one suggests you *can* use what you've got:
[test a file upload using rspec - rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260394/test-a-file-upload-using-rspec-rails)

Also consider it might be something dodgy with rspec not treating :register => {:file =>blah} the same as :register => {'file' => blah}