# Using fixture_file_upload method Rails 4 Rspec

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I am testing the creation of my Image object with FactoryGirl and Rspec.

Orignally i have been doing I am using

```
photo { File.new(File.join(Rails.root, 'spec/fixtures', photo_name)) }
```

but all of a sudden i am getting

```
Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError:
No handler found for "#<File:0x00000003bf15c8>
```

So after reading various posts I have changed to `fixture_file_upload` method but am having trouble creating the object.

images.rb

```
include ActionDispatch::TestProcess
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :image do
    transient do
      photo_name 'validated_image.jpg'
   end
   photo { fixture_file_upload(Rails.root.join('spec', 'fixtures', photo_name), 'image/jpeg') }
end
```

Though originally i tried this as the fixture path was declared in my rails_helper

```
photo { fixture_file_upload photo_name, 'image/jpeg' }
# config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures" # rails_helper
# Would produce error 'validated_image.jpg file does not exist'
```

My current implementation (vey top) doesnt create an instance of Image when doing this

```
it 'creates a new image' do
  expect do
    post :create, image: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:image)
  end.to change(Image, :count).by(1)
end
# ERROR
# expected #count to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0
```

Am i missing anything here?

Thanks

Comment: Finally, are you able to use `fixture_file_upload` with Rspec 4? I've some related issues. I would love to hear your fix.  Thanks!
I finally use `Rack::Test::​UploadedFile.new(file_fixture('my_file.jpeg'))` but I don't know if it's the way to do it.